# Returning object from callback in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I want to wrap the `geocoder.geocodeAddressString` in another method with other logic.

```
public func placemarkForSearchResult<T>(searchResult: T) -> CLPlacemark? {
        if let searchResult = searchResult as? String {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(searchResult, completionHandler: {
                (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                
                // Check for returned placemarks
                if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0 {
                    return placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark // CLPlacemark is not convertible to void error message
                }
                return nil // Typd Void does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible
            })
        }
    }
```

I have some other logic in this method that's not really relevant, but I was wondering how I can handle a situation like this where I want to return a CLPlacemark, but cannot because the completionHandler for the geocoder returns Void.  I cannot change the Void parameter of the geocoder callback.

Is that possible?  Or am I stuck with calling a delegate method that uses the found CLPlacemark from the geocoder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can never return a placemark from your `placemarkForSearchResult` function, because obtaining a placemark requires the use of an *asynchronous* function (`geocodeAddressString`). By that time that function has finished and calls back into your completion handler, your `placemarkForSearchResult` has already finished and returned long ago!

You need a strategy compatible with the asynchronous nature of the function you are calling. Instead of returning a placemark from `placemarkForSearchResult`, you need `placemarkForSearchResult` to *accept a callback function parameter*. When you have your placemark in the completion handler, you *call* that callback function. If that callback function is (cleverly) designed to accept a placemark *parameter*, you are now handing that placemark to whoever called you in the first place.

Comment: And see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30133533/341994 - indeed, your question is effectively a duplicate of that one.

Comment: "Or am I stuck with calling a delegate method that uses the found CLPlacemark from the geocoder" Yes, that's another possible strategy. They are almost the same: in both approaches, you are establishing a line of communication back to your caller, so that _you_ can send the placemark back to your caller in your own sweet asynchronous time. But the "accept a callback function" approach is more lightweight and more flexible, since there is no need to impose a delegate-protocol architecture on your caller.

Comment: just a follow up snippet, if my completion would look like: `completion: (CLPlacemark) -> Void` , how do you pass the callback to the original `placemarkForSearchResult` function since I don't have the actual placemark yet.  Let's say it's supposed to be, `addPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark)`, then how do I pass that as a callback?

Comment: So now you are playing the role of the caller? You would pass `addPlacemark`. But you are more likely to pass an anonymous function, i.e. `{ placemark in // ... code }`. In other words, the way you, as caller, will call `placemarkForSearchResult` is just like the way you are already calling `geocoder.geocodeAddressString`.

Comment: If you don't understand how functions get passed around as values in Swift (though I'm pretty sure you _do_ understand it), see my book, starting about here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_as_value